# How do I make this php codes work the way I want it?

Tags: php

I am trying to put an if statement inside my own php codes, which I'm using for de site I'm creating, but need desperate some help to get things work the way I want it, without damaging the original code.

The codes are written for the creating of translations for random words.

1. first what I do when creating a new word is selecting the word from the [wordslist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WERqq.png).
2. then this [translation table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ccWd.png) appears, by which I can add the translations.
3. then if I click on the save ("добави") button the translations are created.

Unfortunately, when you click on save the translations are created in the database as new one, having new word_id, but they are not linked to the word I'd selected from the wordslist, which actually hase a word_id number.

So basicly, is there any chance to link the translations to existing word_id numbers, rather than creating new one?

Here are the [three php](https://jsfiddle.net/f7q5Loa5/) files I'm currently using:

```
// insert_lang.php

require_once("session.php");
require_once("class.user.php");

$auth_user = new USER();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$stmt_word = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM words WHERE word_id IN (19,20, 21)");
$stmt_word->execute();
$num = $stmt_word->rowCount();
$wordRow=$stmt_word->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($wordRow)
{
    foreach($wordRow as $k => $v)
    {
        $stmt_word1 = $auth_user->runQuery("INSERT INTO word_language_meanings SET word_id = '".$v['word_id']."', word_language = 'English', word_meaning = '".$v['word_name']."'");
        $stmt_word1->execute();

        $stmt_word2 = $auth_user->runQuery("INSERT INTO word_language_meanings SET word_id = '".$v['word_id']."', word_language = 'Български', word_meaning = '".$v['word_name']."'");
        $stmt_word2->execute();

        $stmt_word3 = $auth_user->runQuery("INSERT INTO word_language_meanings SET word_id = '".$v['word_id']."', word_language = 'Гръцки', word_meaning = '".$v['word_name']."'");
        $stmt_word3->execute();

        $stmt_word4 = $auth_user->runQuery("INSERT INTO word_language_meanings SET word_id = '".$v['word_id']."', word_language = 'Латински', word_meaning = '".$v['word_name']."'");
        $stmt_word4->execute();

        $stmt_word5 = $auth_user->runQuery("INSERT INTO word_language_meanings SET word_id = '".$v['word_id']."', word_language = 'Нидерландски', word_meaning = '".$v['word_name']."'");
        $stmt_word5->execute();

        $stmt_word6 = $auth_user->runQuery("INSERT INTO word_language_meanings SET word_id = '".$v['word_id']."', word_language = 'Старобългарски', word_meaning = '".$v['word_name']."'");
        $stmt_word6->execute();

        $stmt_word7 = $auth_user->runQuery("INSERT INTO word_language_meanings SET word_id = '".$v['word_id']."', word_language = 'Старогръцки', word_meaning = '".$v['word_name']."'");
        $stmt_word7->execute();
    }
}

// insert_trans.php
require_once("session.php");
require_once("class.user.php");

$auth_user = new USER();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$word_id = $auth_user->insertQuery("INSERT INTO words SET word_name = '".addslashes($_POST['word_name'])."', word_language = '".addslashes($_POST['word_language'])."', word_status = '1', date_added = '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'");

if(isset($_POST['word_language_meanings']))
{
    foreach($_POST['word_language_meanings'] as $k => $v)
    {
        $stmt_word1 = $auth_user->runQuery("INSERT INTO word_language_meanings SET word_id = '".$word_id."', word_language = '".addslashes($_POST['word_language_meaning_lang'][$k])."', word_meaning = '".addslashes($v)."', date_added = '".date('Y-m-d h:i:s')."'");
        $stmt_word1->execute();
    }
}

//echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); print_r($_FILES); exit;

header('Location: dictionary.php?word_id='.$word_id.'&language='.$_POST['word_language'].'&page=trans');
exit;

// save_trans.php

require_once("session.php");
require_once("class.user.php");

$auth_user = new USER(); 
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$stmt_word = $auth_user->runQuery("UPDATE words SET word_name = '".addslashes($_POST['word_name'])."', word_language = '".addslashes($_POST['word_language'])."' WHERE word_id = '".$_POST['word_id']."'");
$stmt_word->execute();

$stmt_word1 = $auth_user->runQuery("DELETE FROM word_language_meanings WHERE word_id = '".$_POST['word_id']."'");
$stmt_word1->execute();

if(isset($_POST['word_language_meanings']))
{
    foreach($_POST['word_language_meanings'] as $k => $v)
    {
        $stmt_word1 = $auth_user->runQuery("INSERT INTO word_language_meanings SET word_id = '".$_POST['word_id']."', word_language = '".addslashes($_POST['word_language_meaning_lang'][$k])."', word_meaning = '".addslashes($v)."', date_added = '".date('Y-m-d h:i:s')."'");
        $stmt_word1->execute();
    }
}

//echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); print_r($_FILES); exit;

header('Location: dictionary.php?word_id='.$_POST['word_id'].'&language='.$_POST['word_language'].'&page=trans');
exit;
```

Comment: You're only ever doing an INSERT. You might want to check to see if there's an ID, and if so, do an UPDATE instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if the value already exists, you can try by manipulating the code below to your needs until it works. As suggested in the comment, check to see if there's an ID with this code below by using mysqli_num_rows function:

```
$sql0 = "SELECT * FROM word_language_meanings WHERE word_id='".$v['word_id']."', word_language = 'English', word_meaning = '".$v['word_name']."'");
$result0 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql0);
    //check to see if id exists by counting rows found
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result0) > 0) {
    //write a query to do "update" instead of insert
}
else {
    //write a query to insert
}
```

Depending on your needs, you may need to check multiple different id's, if so, it wouldn't be hard to edit this "check if exists" query with minor additions/changes by using "AND"

Comment: I'll check this code and let you now if it works. Also, I have this [two codes](https://jsfiddle.net/ovk4yesL/). Is there maybe anything wrong with?

Comment: I couldn't find anything obvious in the code as far as errors go. If it works when inserting, you know it works. But you have a condition, where if it exists, you do not want to create a new one (which is what insert does). So by checking if the ID exists before your insert queries, you can prevent from making new rows by using update queries whenever the id already exists

Comment: Okay, but where do I need to test the code above. Or do I need to make a new php file where I can combine all of this codes? Thank you!

Comment: I would try to test the code after all of your foreach functions. Put your insert queries where i commented //write a query to insert, then put your update queries (which you need to make easily by changing "insert into" to "update" where I commented //write a query to do "update" instead of insert

Comment: If that doesn't work, you could try adding ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE; to the end of your insert queries. Don't know if it'll work but worth trying. You can read more on this approach here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow. Need first to read whole bunch of files, as I'm not an expert of this kind. Thank you for taking the time to help out.